# How to use private API of the Spartacus library

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Sometimes it happens that a class we want to extend is not a part of Spartacus' public API. Therefore we cannot import directly `SomeClass` from `@spartacus/xxxxx`.

We already found or created a github issue with a proposal to export `SomeClass` in the public API. Now waiting for the response from the Spartacus core team.

What can we do in the meantime if we **really** need to import it and extend in our project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you need a private API member of Spartacus, please first:

- search for a relevant request to make it public in [Spartacus github issues](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues)
- if there is no issue for that, please [create a new issue](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/new).

**Disclaimer: The private API of Spartacus should not be used in general. It may change at any time without any warning. You can use the following workaround on your OWN RISK. It might result in breaking your code after upgrading to any next version.**

Open file `node_modules/@spartacus/xxxxx/spartacus-xxxxx.d.ts` and find the exported alias name for the class, prefixed with symbol `ɵ`:

```js
export { SomeClass as ɵxyz } from '..........';
```

Then you can use the alias in your application, for example to extend the class behavior:

```js
import { ɵxyz as SomeClass } from `@spartacus/core`;

/* ... */

// for example:
@Injectable()
export class CustomSomeClass extends SomeClass { 
  /*...*/ 
}

/* ... */
@NgModule({
  providers: [
     { provide: SomeClass, useClass: CustomSomeClass }
  ]
})
```

**WARNING: the `ɵ`-alias might change in any next release of Spartacus without any warning. It's not a part of the public API.**